# How to move islands in a highmap

Tags: highcharts, geojson

I got a map from Spain that include Canary Island but the islands are so far and the map looks very small, is there any way to move the islands closer to Spain?

Comment: You will have to edit the map yourself if you cannot find an existing one that shows the Canary Island in an insert. In which format is your current map?

Comment: It's a json file

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts [provide a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sv9mxhxb) of how to move certain countries. You can use the added functionality provided there to the `Point` class to move your areas into position. We will utilize the following (slightly modified) code:

```
// Offset an SVG path by x and y
Highcharts.Point.prototype.offsetPath = function (x, y, redraw, animate) {
    var path = this.path || [],
        isX = true,
        i = 0;
    for (; i < path.length; ++i) {
        if (Highcharts.isNumber(path[i])) {
            path[i] += isX ? x : y;
            isX = !isX;
        }
    }
    this.update({
        dataLabels: {
            x: this.series.xAxis.toPixels(x) - this.series.xAxis.toPixels(0),
            y: this.series.yAxis.toPixels(y) - this.series.yAxis.toPixels(0)
        },
        path: path
    }, redraw, animate);
};
```

To move the points. Then, after loading your map of Spain, you can post-process to move the areas into the desired position. I've made an example here ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/094ny17g/)):

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    // ...
}, function(chart) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.series[0].points.length; i++) {
        if(this.series[0].points[i]['hc-key'] == 'es-me') { // Melilla
            this.series[0].points[i].offsetPath(0, -900, true, false);
        } else if(this.series[0].points[i]['hc-key'] == 'es-gc') { // Las Palmas
            this.series[0].points[i].offsetPath(-1200, 0, true, false);
        } else if(this.series[0].points[i]['hc-key'] == 'es-tf') { // Tenerife
            this.series[0].points[i].offsetPath(-1200, 0, true, false);
        } else if(this.series[0].points[i]['hc-key'] == 'es-pm') { // Baleares
            this.series[0].points[i].offsetPath(-800, 0, true, false);
        }
    }
});
```

This moves Melilla, Las Palmas, Tenerife and Baleares closer by X and Y values provided in the example (1st and 2nd parameter), as well as redrawing (3rd parameter), but not animating (4th parameter).

The [normal map of Spain would look like this JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/es/es-all) provided by Highcharts.